# Theme and Icons Problem with GTK3 Installed with vcpkg

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gtk3, vcpkg

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 and am trying to use GTK in C++ and installed it using vcpkg.

I've installed GTK using `vcpkg` according to the [guide from GTK](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php). I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and it is able to compile and run the example program [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html), but there is an issue regarding the theme and icons. According to the installation guide, under the section **Building and distributing your application** there are some things that must be done to get themes and icons to work.

I've started by downloading the Windows theme the guide suggests and have it in a `share` directory and then I've created a `settings.ini` file in an `etc` directory. It says to place this in the "install directory", which I assume is where Visual Studio is placing the exe for the program. I've tried it in both build and release, in the source files, in the top project directory - all with no success (and I did make sure it is targeting x64).

Just in case I also tried placing these where vcpkg is installed as well as where vcpkg installs gtk. No luck. When the program runs I get the warning

```
(gtkExample0.exe:16772): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not find the icon 'window-minimize-symbolic-ltr'. The 'hicolor' theme
was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
        http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
```

So it seems that it is never finding the `ssettings.ini` file telling it to use the Windows 10 theme. Has anyone had any luck with getting this to work (both from VS2019 debugging runs and in deployment)?

---

To summarize the files:

`share\themes\Windows10\gtk-3.0\gtk-3.20\` (downloaded from suggested GitHub repo)

`etc\settings.ini` contains:

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name=Windows10
gtk-font-name=Segoe UI 9
```

I've placed these in

`<VS2019Project>\x64\Release`,

`<VS2019Project>\x64\Debug`,

`C:<path_to_vcpkg>\vcpkg\packages\gtk_x64-windows`,

`C:<path_to_vcpkg>\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows`

All with no change when running from VS2019 under Release or Debug.

Comment: I've switched to using VS Code and a MinGW installation that, with a lot of finagling, I can run a GTK app with icons and everything. Will leave the question up in case anyone knows how to get it working with vcpkg.

Comment: can you help me to setup the gtk with vscode as I get a error saying that It cannot find gtk/gtk.h

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theme and icons considered as external resources are not distributed by vcpkg, and the instructions given in the distribution guide from GTK regarding where these resources should be layout on windows 10 are not crystal clear. The problem has also been reported here [vcpkg issue#4417](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/4417).

The solution proposed hereunder is to install 
all the resources in the `<VS2019Project>\x64\Release` directory of your VS project where your .exe application lives [This is a local solution the problem. A global approach should consider the setting of some user-defined free desktop environment variables which is not discussed here]. Icons can be picked from an ancillary MSYS2 distribution and the theme as indicated in the [GTK Guide](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php). The solution should be replicated for the Debug branch.

1. Supposing you have MSYS2, install `mingw-w64-x86_64-adwaita-icon-theme` package with the `pacman` package manager if not already done on your MSYS2 installation `pacman -Syu mingw-w64-x86_64-adwaita-icon-theme`.
2. Copy `C:\msys64\mingw64\share\icons` to `<VS2019Project>\x64\Release\share\icons`
   you should get both `hicolor` and `Adwaita` icons as subdirectories of your target dir.
3. Copy the theme resources downloaded in the source `gtk-3.20` directory directly into `<VS2019Project>\x64\Release\share\themes\Windows10\gtk-3.0\`. Do not locate these resources into a `gtk-3.20` subfolder: to understand why consult this article [Theme Location](https://www.linux.org/threads/installing-obtaining-and-making-gtk-themes.11811/) [assuming here that no global desktop environment variable has been set].
4. Create a `<VS2019Project>\x64\Release\etc\gtk-3.0` directory, put your `settings.ini` into it.
5. Recompile and you should obtain a windows 10 look and feel for your application window.

[image: Gtk Hello]

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I struggled quite a bit with setting this up, because I tried to use the share directory  of my projects vcpkg installation in `vcpkg\installed\x64-windows` but had no luck with it...